# Could you clarify this verse 28:38

Tags: verses

I spoke to two jewish teens they said that the verse where phrioh says to his cheif hamad to build a palace mounting to the heavens to reach the God of Moses cannot be correct as one of these cheifs was not alive at the time of phiroh.

It this true.

They also mentioned qaroon the other cheif, could someone find out for me if both these cheif were alive at he time of phrioh as it is mentioned in the quran

Comment: Visit the islamic-awareness site.

Answer (score 0):

The event referred to in this verse is not recorded in the Torah. The Jews probably understood that it's referring to the Tower of Babel recorded in the Torah which is indeed another time and not in Egypt. It has similarities but it is not the same event.